# URL is updating but Ajax call still going to old one

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am editing someone else project and they have used a lot of DOM which I'm not familiar with.

First select box

```
<select name="task_projectid" id="task_projectid"
 data-assigned-dropdown="assigned"
 data-ajax--url="/feed/projects?ref=general"></select>
```

When user select project I'm using following to update the data-ajax--url in task_itemid

```
$(document).on('change', '#task_projectid', function() {
  $('#task_itemid').attr('data-ajax--url', '/feed/items?ref=' + this.value);
});
```

here is task_itemid box

```
<select name="task_itemid" id="task_itemid" 
data-assigned-dropdown="assigned" 
data-ajax--url="/feed/items?ref=">
</select>
```

It's working and url on task_itemid changed to

```
/feed/items?ref=4
```

But the Ajax call still going to

```
/feed/items?ref=
```

Please help.

I found this

```
$(".js-select2-basic-search-modal").select2({
        theme: "bootstrap",
        width: null,
        containerCssClass: ':all:',
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
        ajax: {
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: function (params) {
                var queryParameters = {
                    term: params.term
                }
                return queryParameters;
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.value,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. You haven't shown the code which *reads* the value.

Comment: It's another identical select box. But I'll add that. thanks for the feedback

Comment: You still haven't show the code that reads the value. You said "But the Ajax call still going to", but there's no Ajax call in the question. We can't see how it is determining what URL it should be using.

Comment: oh I see, I'm not sure how that part is working. I'll dig more.

Comment: @Quentin I found something, please check if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes):

> It is recommended that you declare your configuration options by passing in an object when initializing Select2. However, you may also define your configuration options by using the HTML5 data-* attributes, which will override any options set **when initializing Select2** and any defaults.

You're changing the attribute, but by that time Select2 has already been initialised and read the old value.

I think you can use the [dynamic urls feature](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#dynamic-urls) to read the value when the Ajax request is triggered.

```
ajax: {
    url: () => $('#task_itemid').attr('data-ajax--url'),
```

I haven't tested this, and it might override the logic for adding a query string to the URL, in which case you'll need to make that function add the data from `params.term` too.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had to copy the whole thing in frontend with dynamic url. And it worked